# quickstart jboss (or tomcat) + beans tutorial

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm a little daunted by the endless myriad options in Eclipse for starting a Java EE project that would run on jboss.  I know what I'm doing once I have an environment that's configured, but was hoping someone could point me to a step by step tutorial on how to go from writing my first class to actually having jboss pick it up on startup and act on it.

I assume the tutorial would need to involve the part of the task that has ANT generate a war file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EJB 3 Tutorial explaining Ant and showing how to create a session and entity beans with annotations and JBoss](http://www.laliluna.de/ejb-3-ant-tutorial-jboss.html)

Comment: The link above is broken, here is the updated one: http://www.laliluna.de/articles/ejb-3-struts-tutorial-jboss.html