# JBoss Tutorials, Portal

Tags: jboss, jboss-portal

I am a bit daunted by all the information that is available on JBoss.  I searched through various tutorials on their website, but there is a lot there - some of which is over my head as someone new to JBoss.  The tutorial [recommended to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791554/quickstart-jboss-or-tomcat-beans-tutorial) is good, but I also need a tutorial involving JBoss Portal.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jboss.org/community/community/wiki?view=overview

Comment: Yeah.  I did already find that.  I was really hoping for something like the JBoss walkthrough (provided in my question) for JBoss Portal.

Thanks, though.  I'll mark as an answer unless I get a better response.